# diskfull で mongod が起動しなくなったので、あるコレクションを削除したい

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB を amazon-linux 上で動かしていたところ、ディスクフルで起動しなくなりました。

```
2017-09-25T06:06:23.039+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2017-09-25T06:06:23.039+0000 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongo/journal or use --smallfiles
2017-09-25T06:06:23.039+0000 [initandlisten]
2017-09-25T06:06:23.039+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
```

ログ的データをためているコレクションが原因なので、これを削除しようと考えたのですが、これを実現する方法はありますでしょうか？

- サービス自体が起動していない (`sudo service mongod start` が失敗する) ので、 mongo シェルが使えない状態です。
- ec2 インスタンスなので、ディスクサイズを拡張してやればいいとは思いますが、それはそれでちょっと面倒だと考えています。
- オペレーションツールがあって、 mongod を起動せずともコレクションを削除できる、が理想なのですが。。こういったツールはありますでしょうか？

#### 追記:

- mongodb バージョン: v2.6.12
- ストレージの変更など: 特に行っていなく、デフォルトの設定

Comment: ジャーナルファイルが作れなくて死んでいるようですが、それを直接解決する方法はさておいてデータファイルを直接削除することが出来るか知りたい、ということでしょうか。

Comment: @suzukis データファイルの容量は、今発生している 3.3G 足りません、の 4G より多い(はず、メインのデータはこのログ的データのみなので。) ので、データを削除できれば、ひとまずまた動くようになると考えています。そして、その方法があったらいいなと思い、質問しています。

Comment: ちょっと調べてみましたがバージョンと設定によってストレージエンジンが異なりそれによってファイル構造も変わります。バージョンと、デフォルト値以外のストレージエンジンを設定されてるようならそれを書かれた方がいいでしょう。

Comment: @suzukis バージョン情報と、ストレージ関連の設定について追記いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Satoshi Okano さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/38210/754) を見て、 mongod を起動させないといけなさそうだ、と思うようになりました。そして、ひとまず、ディスクサイズは変更せずに復旧できるにはできたので、そのまとめです。

#### 1. journaling を off にする

`/etc/mongodb.conf` を編集し、以下の行を追加する

```
nojournal=true
```

そうすると、 jounaling を行わずに起動できるので、ひとまず mongod サービスは立ち上がる。

#### 2. `sudo service mongod restart`

#### 3. 該当データ(が入ったDB を) db.dropDatabase()

ひとまず mongo のシェルが起動できるようになるので、データを削除する。

このとき、 `db.COLLECTION.drop()` そして `db.repairDatabase()` では、下記のエラーメッセージが表示されて、使用領域の解法ができなかった。

> Cannot repair database test having size: ... because free disk space is : ...

なので、下記を実行し、該当データが入ったデータベースごと drop する。

```
use データベース
db.dropDatabase()
```

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625261/cannot-repair-database-having-size

#### 4. jounaling の設定をオフにして、起動しなおす。

```
# /etc/mongodb.conf を編集したのちに
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: 知りたいのは「mongodbが起動しない状態でデータファイルを削除する方法」ではなかったのですか？質問と回答の方向がずれていますが。

Comment: 「mongodbが起動しない状態でデータファイルを削除する方法」が理想でしたが、 @SatoshiOkano さんの記述をみて、そうか、それはできないのか、と理解しました。じゃあ、どうやったら手元のこいつ(mongodb)を動かせるようになるのかしら、といじってみていった結果、ひとまず復旧できたので、「やった！忘れないうちに」と思いこの投稿を記述しました。

指摘を受けて考えてみると、そのことに言及しないのは、、なんというかフェアではないと思ったので、投稿を修正しました。

Answer (score 0):

2.6のマニュアルにて[MongoDB Package Components](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/program/)を見る限り、標準で同梱されているコマンドとして、「mongodを起動せずともコレクションを削除できる」というものは無いようです。

残念ながら、ディスクサイズ拡張して何とかするのが最も早いということになるのではないかと思います。

Comment: 解決方法の第一選択は、エラーメッセージに書いてあるとおり--smallfileを指定して小さなジャーナルファイルを使用することです